# Recursively take obj file for linking

Tags: c, makefile

There is a small problem in Makefile. Whenever I write this, it works well

```
OBJDIR:=.obj
OBJ := A.o B.o
```

.
.
.

```
A:  $(OBJDIR)/A.o $(OBJDIR)/B.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ $^
```

The compilation goes like this ....

.... `-g -O0 -DWITH_POSIX -Iinclude/ -o A .obj/A.o .obj/B.o`

But instead, if I write this, it wnly takes first object file

```
A:  $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJ)
```

The compilation then ....
.... `-g -O0 -DWITH_POSIX -Iinclude/ -o A .obj/A.o B.o`

It should take recursively from directory. probably I am missing the correct way to handle this. Anyone have a sugestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/),

```
A: $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(OBJ))
A: $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(OBJ))
A: $(foreach obj,$(OBJ),$(OBJDIR)/$(obj))
```

will all do the same thing.

Comment: precise. Thanks a lot.